# Accelerometer to cm - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, accelerometer, measure

[image]

I have this result for my accelerometer , I would like to convert this to cm. what conversion would I have to do?

(.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIAccelerometerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *xlabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *ylabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *zlabel;

}
@end
```

(.m)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer]setDelegate:self];
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view,typically from a nib
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:
  (UIAcceleration *)acceleration{
    [xlabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",acceleration.x]];
    [ylabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",acceleration.y]];
    [zlabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",acceleration.z]];
}

@end
```

Is it possible to find the distance by using accelerometer?

Thanks for answers, thanks for people who took the time to help.

Comment: [`UIAccelerationValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIAccelerationValue) is in units of "g" (or g-force)...

Comment: Please use answer and please elaborate on your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You can't simply convert acceleration to distance - they have different dimensions. You can integrate over time, but that will be very noisy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more like a physical question :)

There are two situations:

1.The iPhone device did not have any *attitude adjustment* while moving in 3D.

2.The iPhone is falt on the table.

Considering your y-value, I guess what you want it's more fit to the first situation.

To calculate the displacement in a line, you can use the formula below.

[image]

While ***Vi*** - the velocity of iPhone at the beginning point,

***a***  - the acceleration in your direction (assume is uniform acceleration)

Well, If you acclerate from motionless, ***Vi*** = 0, Then it became:

***`distance = 1/2 * acceleration * time * time.`***

And the UIAcceleration definition:

`UIAcceleration` -

> This type is used to store acceleration values, which are specified as g-force values, where the value 1.0 corresponds to the normal acceleration caused by gravity at the Earth’s surface.

`timeStamp` -

> This value indicates the time relative to the device CPU time base register. Compare acceleration event timestamps to determine the elapsed time between them. Do not use a timestamp to determine the exact time at which an event occurred.

So with the `x`, `y`, `z` and `timeStamp` property in [`UIAcceleration Class`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAcceleration/y),

You can figure out the displacement of each single direction. To calculate the whole displacement in space:

[image]

[See Also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Representations)

### *This is just a method how to calculate it under a number of assumptions, howerver, your question is not clear about the time, it can't work out in this condition you had provided so far.*

Comment: Dont worry I figured it out using a bit of your solution and a bit of mine. ;]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the accelerometer to measure XYZ displacement, without additional constraints. The iPhone lacks a high-quality gyroscope, so it's unable to determine if the phone rotates.

For simplicity, imagine the phone sitting on a table. The (x,y,z) acceleration values you get from UIAcceleration will read something close to (0,0,1) [or maybe -1, I don't remember which way the Z axis points]. If you move the phone from left to right, the X-axis values will change, and you can integrate those changes over the time between updates to get an approximation of the X-coordinate position of the phone. However, you can then rotate the phone 90 degrees, and then when you move it left and right, the Y values will change instead. There's no way to tell that this has happened, so you can't tell is the phone is "actually" moving in a particular direction.

You can use the compass to get rotation information, but it's not a very good reference (it's affected by nearby metal, and doesn't update as quickly as the accelerometer).